# Regex terminated with , or }

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex in order to match any item of this kind:

```
TURTLE=1,
DOG,
CAT}
BABY=3}
```

I had write this regular expression:

```
 ([a-zA-Z_0-9]+[ ]*=?[ ]*[0-9]*[\t\n ]*(,|\})
```

But it doesn't work in these case:

```
CAT
}
```

Could someone explain me why `[\t\n ]*` doesn't work as I expect (*doesn't skip any space tab etc...*)?

Comment: Regex != Regex. Are we talking POSIX regex, PCRE, JavaScript regex, sed, ...? Some regex matchers work on a per-line basis and have no way to work across multiple lines.

Comment: Possibly try adding `\r` to `[\t\n ]*`?

Comment: Not clear what your regex is supposed to match. Can there be any number of line breaks between the word and the `}`, or just one? Can there be more text before the `}`, or just the `}` as the only character on that line?

Comment: just the } after text.
any number of newline allowd.

Comment: It seems work with \r, what \r means?

Comment: `\r` is the carriage return. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) explains new lines on different systems. Since you're probably on a Windows the lines in text files would end with a carriage-return and a linefeed : `\r\n`.

Comment: So, would `CA\n\n\nT}` also match? What about `CA}T\n\nCAT}`? Would that match `CA}` and `CAT}`, or just `CAT}`, or `CA}T\n\nCAT}`?

Comment: Correcting the unbalanced parentheses, it does work. Somewhat simplified - [here's what it does at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aX3nZ5/2).

Comment: When in doubt you can use a tool to evaluate your regexp against test data. This is a tool I use often. https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
([a-zA-Z_0-9]+[ ]*)=?[ ]*[0-9]*[\t\r\n ]*[,}]{1}
```

Concerning your version:

```
([a-zA-Z_0-9]+[ ]*=?[ ]*[0-9]*[\t\n ]*(,|\})
```

You haven't close bracket and for detecting all newlines also you should take into account return carriage '\r'.